# How do you close a workspace in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-18.04

- Super+PageUp/Down to open
- Shift+Super+PageUp/Down to move window to a different workspace
- ????????????????? to close a workspace

It's sad I have to even say this. Believe it or not I have already tried finding an answer to this question.

How do you close a workspace in GNOME(specifically, Ubuntu 18.04)?

Comment: For me, unnused desktops in Ubuntu 22.04 are NOT automatically removed. I turned off all extensions yet empty desktops stay on right side. How to remove it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Workspaces are automatically closed when you remove all the windows from it and switch to another one. I'm not entirely sure, but I think on Ubuntu 18.04 it might also keep one open at the bottom so you can drag windows into it.

Also see:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047051/remove-a-gnome-workspace

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

- `Ctrl+Alt+left/right arrow` can switch the workspace
- `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+left/right arrow` can bring your current window to the target workspace(create a new one if not exists)
  on Gnome Classic

In addition to that the size of workspace is configurable. Which also defines the behavior whether a workspace will be closed while no using.